# How do I rephrase this implication to be less hand-wavy?

Tags: proof-writing

I have a homework problem asking me to prove that it's impossible to construct a set of integers so that the set has certain characteristics. I've showed the following things:

1. It's impossible to construct a set of **integers modulo 100** so that the set has the required characteristics.
2. Any set of integers with the required characteristics cannot contain two integers which are equivalent modulo 100.

How do I conclude the target assertion from these two facts? I would probably get full credit if I played the "clearly" card, but it isn't really clear (to me). Is there some simple proof by contradiction here which I'm not seeing?

Comment: Too abstract! Please tell us what the question is. And then, What have you showed! This way, we can tell you, how to conclude.

Comment: @KannappanSampath I think that any more detail will just confuse what I'm trying to ask. If you can, just imagine that the detail is left unspecified and you have to give a proof with only the information I gave. That will give me exactly what I need. :) But if you're really curious, the homework question is asking me to prove that it's impossible to construct a set of 52 different integers such that no two of them have a sum or difference divisible by 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on just what you mean by (1). If you mean that no set whose members are pairwise incongruent modulo $100$ can have the required characteristics, then you’re done: (1) and (2) impose contradictory requirements on a set having the required characteristics. If, on the other hand, you mean that no subset of $\{0,1,\dots,99\}$ has the required properties, then you need to show something like this:

> (3) If $S$ is a set of integers with the required properties, $n\in S$, $m\equiv n\pmod{100}$, and you form a new set $S'$ by replacing $n$ by $m$, (i.e., $S'=(S\setminus{m})\cup{m}$), then $S'$ also has the desired properties.

Then you can argue as follows. Suppose that $S$ is a set of integers with the required characteristics. Using (3) repeatedly, replace each member of $S$ by the unique member of $\{0,1,\dots,99\}$ congruent to it. The resulting set set still has the required characteristics, contradicting (1).

Comment: Thanks, I think the ambiguity in what exactly I mean by "integers modulo 100" is why I was having a hard time being formal about my conclusion. By explicitly choosing one of your options I can see that the proof will come together much more nicely. Thanks!